# About NSURLSessionTask and "resume"

Tags: ios, nsurl

I wish to clarify the meaning of "resume". It is used to start a session task according to Apple's documentation.

My question is if the task is "resume" the second time before the first "resume" completes its operation, does the second "resume" would just ask the task to continue work from the first call without starting from the very beginning?

That is, if the task has been started and paused for whatever reasons the second "resume" call would just resume what the task had been doing.

Secondly, if the task has not been stopped or paused at all, the second "resume" call would have no effect and the task would just continue to do what it is supposed to do ...

Hope that somebody who knows if the above 2 assumptions are correct can give some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSURLSessionTask` can be in one of four states;

- Active
- Suspended
- Cancelled
- Completed

Calling `resume` only has an effect if the task is currently suspended.

A task starts in the suspended state, so you must call `resume` initially to start it.

Calling `resume` on an active, completed or cancelled task has no effect.

You can suspend a task by calling `suspend`.

The effect of calling `resume` on a suspended task depends on the type of task;

- An `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` can be resumed from where it was suspended.
- All other task types are restarted.

Comment: Suppose the ios device is out of battery half way during a session download  and  the device is connected to a power source and up again.  Then the user restart the APP and the same download request is made from the same code without any reference to the first call. Would ios  just continue to download (without starting from the beginning) without having the APP coder to add code to check the status of the first download request?

Comment: Assuming that you mean that the device actually turns off, then no.  Once the specific task is removed from memory it can't be resumed; So after the device reboots and you restart your app, the download would resume from the beginning.

Comment: are you implying that if the device has not been turned off, the download task can continue to download (without having to start from the beginning) if the "resume" call is made the second time even if the user had quited the APP or pushed the APP into the background after the first "resume" ...

Comment: If they force quite the app, the download will probably be terminated.  If they have moved the app to the background and you have specified a background `NSURLSession` then iOS completes the download on your app's behalf.